# Calabash Android: how to run or execute tests on all connected devices?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, functional-testing, calabash

I  know I can trigger tests on multiple devices using

`ADB_DEVICE_ARG=<serial_number> TEST_SERVER_PORT=<port_number> calabash-android run <apk>`

but this is quite manual, where I have to manually launch a new Terminal instance and type those commands for each device.

Is there a way I can trigger the Calabash tests to run on all *connected* devices?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with the sh script like

```
NUM=`expr $(adb devices | wc -l) - 1`
DEVICES_LIST=`adb devices | tail -$NUM | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`
PORT_NUMBER=34777

for DEVICE in $DEVICES_LIST; do \
  ADB_DEVICE_ARG=$DEVICE TEST_SERVER_PORT=$PORT_NUMBER calabash-android run <apk>
  PORT_NUMBER=`expr $PORT_NUMBER+1`
done
```

Comment: I have saved the script as `devices.sh`.   After `chmod 755`, when I run it, this is the error I see:  `./devices.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token newline'`      `./devices.sh: line 6: ADB_DEVICE_ARG=$DEVICE TEST_SERVER_PORT=$PORT_NUMBER calabash-android run <apk>'`